# Mounting network volume via the command line is OS X

Tags: macos, webdav, mount

If I type Ctrl-K in Finder, and connect to a WebDAV server (http://192.168.1.133:8080, for example), I end up with with a mounted volume at /Volumes/192.168.1.133/

I would like to achieve the same thing on the command line.  Can you suggest a way to do this?

(Specifically, this is the WebDAV server running within the GoodReader app on my iPad.)

Thanks.

Comment: [How to mount WebDav filesystem on Mac?](http://superuser.com/q/699271/172747)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question should properly go to serverfault.

That said, read [mount_webdav (8)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mount_webdav.8.html)